# Upgrading Red Hat 9 (Shrike) kernel manually

Tags: kernel, rhel, rpm, upgrade

I am following the instructions [here](http://www.redhat.com/support/resources/howto/kernel-upgrade/s1-before-upgrade.html) on how to manually perform a kernel upgrade in Red Hat.

The current Kernel RPM's are:

```
kernel-2.4.20-8
kernel-headers is not installed
kernel-ibcs is not installed
kernel-pcmcia-cs-3.1.31-13
kernel-source is not installed

mkinitrd-3.4.42-1
SysVinit-2.84-13
initscripts-7.14-1
```

Under the "Getting the updates" section, all the links are dead, and there doesn't seem to be a `ftp://updates.redhat.com/9.0/en/os/i386/`

Does anybody know where the packages can be downloaded from?

**Edit**

Realising now that RH9 support was dropped a few hundred years ago along with the legacy project, found a working mirror here http://ftp-stud.fht-esslingen.de/

Comment: Could you post your solution as an answer and accept it so the question can be marked as answered?

Comment: done and dusted bud

Answer (score 1):

Using a [mirror](http://ftp-stud.fht-esslingen.de/Mirrors/download.fedoralegacy.org/redhat/9/updates/i386/) of the [fedora legacy website](http://fedoralegacy.org/), I could download a new version of the kernel. By carefully following the steps [here](http://www.redhat.com/support/resources/howto/kernel-upgrade/s1-before-upgrade.html)(for the section "Getting the updates", use the [mirror](http://ftp-stud.fht-esslingen.de/Mirrors/download.fedoralegacy.org/redhat/9/updates/i386/)), I managed to successfully upgrade the kernel.

I messed it up the first time by inputting the incorrect root partition into the "lilo.conf" file. Furthermore, in RH9 it is called "lilo.conf.anaconda". The ".anaconda" extension must be removed.